# Java create an instance of enum via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I want to get an instance to an enum type, so that:

```
String enumString="abc";
MyClass.MyEnum enumType=Class.forName("com.MyClass.MyEnum."+enumString);
```

This gives me an inconvertible types.

Comment: If you know the type at compile-time, why do you need reflection?

Comment: I declared a String for simplify the code. Obviously in my code the enumString is not hardcoded, but passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `MyClass.MyEnum.valueOf(enumString)`. No need to fully qualify the class in the string.

Answer (score 24):

[Enum.valueOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) will do it, but it is pretty picky about it's type.  Make sure you cast the `Class` to `Class<? extends Enum>`.  Example:

```
enum Foo {
    BLAT,
    BLARG
};

System.out.println(Enum.valueOf((Class<? extends Enum>)Class.forName("Foo"), "BLARG"));
```

Comment: Why would reflection be required? Why not just MyEnum e = Enum.valueOf( MyEnum.class, "abc");

Comment: The author of the original question suggested they'd be using reflection by using `Class.forName` and tagging the question with the `reflection` tag.  The tricky part is that the return type of `forClass` is not the right type to pass to `Enum.valueOf`.

Comment: If you know the enum type at compile time, as in the author's sample code, then reflection is not required.

Comment: The question is "Java create an instance of enum **via reflection**".  The sample code is probably just illustrating an approach that didn't work.

Comment: We don't have enough information to know whether reflection is a requirement for this user, or an implementation detail presumed necessary. Hence bozho's question above, and my clarification for the person asking the question. This is not a criticism of you, merely a clarification.

Comment: @AndyThomas "Why would reflection be required?" Because the class is not known at compile time. That is likely not the case for the OP since the other answer was accepted, but that would be the reason nonetheless. I have just such a situation, which is why I'm here (didn't realize Enum had a valueOf that takes a class). I need to handle String user input which could be any possible enum type (not just value), even one that doesn't exist yet. Reflection is completely necessary in my case, even if not in the OP's.

Comment: Also, in my specific case, I need to go one step further and guarantee that the arbitrary enum type is also a subtype of a specific interface and return the enum value as that other type. "enum MyE implements MyI" it needs to work only for all enums of `MyI` which are not all known up front. For future readers: after using the method in the above answer, I then also cast it to `MyI` with `MyI.class.cast( Enum.valueOf( foundClass, enumValue ) );` I lazily (not suggested) let my exception handler catch invalid casts, but you can check if `MyI.class.isInstance( Enum.valueOf(...) )`

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [Enum.valueOf( Class enumType,
                                            String name ).](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)